# Passing as parameter a function that prints a text, executing it after new state in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, event-handling

<sup>[*EDIT3: a single file with almost full code:*</sup>

https://github.com/agutie58/landOfLispInHaskell/blob/main/exampleLoLTextGameHaskell.hs

<sup>*EDIT2: an example of the actual game.*]</sup>

---

<sup>[*Original question*]</sup>
I have a function `run` that is based on a `Domain`, and a list of events:

- if all events are treated, it listens for new events and
- if they are events, it treats several of them.

The majority of events modifies the `Domain`:

```
data Domain =   Domain (String, World) deriving (Show)
data World = World {loc :: String, descSites :: [(Key,String)], mapSites :: [(Key, [Lloc])], objects:: [Key], siteObjects::[(Key,String)]}  deriving (Show)


run :: Domain -> [Event] -> IO ()
run dm [] = do
  events <- uiUpdate dm
  run dm events

run _ (EventExit:_) =
  return ()

run dm (e:es) =
  run (dmUpdate dm e) es
```

The part that I want to focus on is `run (dmUpdate dm e) es`, where `dmUpdate dm e` returns a `Domain` value:

One example of this function `dmUpdate` that works well is:

```
dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event  ->  Domain

dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =  look (snd v) 
                                               
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventWalk direction) =  walk direction (snd v) 

dmUpdate dm _ _ = dm
```

where:

```
look :: World -> Domain
walk :: String -> World -> Domain
-- etc.
```

I want to render (print to console) the result of a new state. For example:

```
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =  do let newDomain = look (snd v) 
                                          putStr (fst newDomain)
                                          newDomain
```

But it does not work.  I try to compute a new state of the world, then do I/O and then try to return `newDomain` as a parameter.

I thought to pass a function like this:

```
run dm (e:es) =
  run (dmUpdate dm e renderMsg) es
  where renderMsg txt = (putStr txt) >> (hFlush stdout)
```

...in order to do somthing like:

```
-- dmUpdate :: dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO () -> Domain
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) (renderMsg) =  let newDomain = look (snd v) 
                                               renderMsg (fst newDomain)
```

But does not work.

Any ideas!?  Thanks in advance!

---

<sup>[*EDIT1*]</sup>
I also tried :

```
  dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event  -> IO Domain
    dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =  do let newDomain = look (snd v) 
                                          putStr (fst newDomain)
                                          newDomain
                                                                                        
    
    dmUpdate dm _ _ = () dm
```

... but I got this message:

```
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( textGameMain.hs, interpreted )

textGameMain.hs:25:1: error:
    Equations for ‘dmUpdate’ have different numbers of arguments
      textGameMain.hs:(25,1)-(27,47)
      textGameMain.hs:33:1-23
   |
25 | dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =  do let newDomain = look (snd v) 
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

textGameMain.hs:70:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Domain’
                  with actual type ‘IO Domain’
    • In the first argument of ‘run’, namely ‘(dmUpdate dm e)’
      In the expression: run (dmUpdate dm e) es
      In an equation for ‘run’: run dm (e : es) = run (dmUpdate dm e) es
   |
70 |   run (dmUpdate dm e ) es
```

So then, I tried to change `run`:

```
run dm (e:es) =
  run () (dmUpdate dm e ) es
```

But I did not manage to make it work... :S

---

<sup>[*EDIT2*]</sup>
So, my code does this (it is based on [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/), and it is an adaptation to Haskell) :

```
    *Main> main
    WORLD> look
    you are in the living-room. a wizard is snoring loudly on the couch.
    There is door going west from here.
    There is ladder going upstairs from here.
    You see a whiskey on the floor.
    You see a bucket on the floor. 
    
    WORLD> walk west
    WORLD> look
    you are in a beautiful garden. there is a well in front of you.
    There is door going east from here.
    You see a frog on the floor.
    You see a chain on the floor.
```

---

<sup>[*EDIT3*]</sup>
(Full code - in fact I collapsed two files into a single one for simplicity...can adding a file be done in some other manner !?)

https://github.com/agutie58/landOfLispInHaskell/blob/main/exampleLoLTextGameHaskell.hs

```
ghci exampleLoLTextGameHaskell.hs
main
```

(...and then, something to EDIT2...)

Comment: That `do let` looks badly indented, putting all the code into the `let`. The last two lines should be part of the `do` instead -- decrease their indentation.

Comment: From your code samples (though not from your type signatures) it would seem that  you intend function `dmUpdate`  to do some text output. So it has to return some `IO Domain` value not just a plain  `Domain ` value. Possible signature: `dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO Domain`

Comment: I tried but without success. I tried : ```dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event  -> IO Domain
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =  do let newDomain = look (snd v) 
                                      putStr (fst newDomain)
                                      newDomain
                                                                                    

dmUpdate dm _ _ = () dm  ```

Comment: (see EDIT1 better! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is far from complete, holds a lot of - for your question - unncesseary parts. I copied your code, simpliefied a little, and made some guessing work. Here is my "fixed" version.

```hs
module Tmp where
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

{-| Be clear about your types. Introducing type alisases helps others read your code.
 I simply guessed that the string-part of the Domain is the UI state -}
type UIState = String
data Domain = Domain (UIState,World) deriving Show
data World = World {loc:: Int} deriving Show

-- | I Have only implemented two directions, so that this example is easy to work with.
data Dir = L | R deriving (Read, Show)

{- | These were the event types that you had in your code. I elaborated them a little. 
By using the "deriving (Read)" we get a low-code input mechanism, but you should probalbly write
your own input parser
-} 
data Event = EventExit | EventWalk Dir| EventLook deriving (Read)

-- | The run-loop now has TWO steps. Render UI and get new events. Process events. Finally recurse.
run :: Domain -> [Event] -> IO ()
run dm [] = uiUpdate dm >> getAction >>= run dm
run _ (EventExit:_) = return ()
run dm (e:es) = run (dmUpdate dm e) es

{-| Update the domain when a single event acts on it -}
dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> Domain
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =  look (snd v) 
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventWalk direction) =  walk direction (snd v)
dmUpdate dm _ = dm

look w = Domain ("You are at coordinate " ++ (show .loc $ w), w)
walk L w@World{loc=l}= Domain ("You went left", w{loc=l-1})
walk R w@World{loc=l} = Domain  ("You went right", w{loc=l+1})

{-| Present the "output" that the domain holds for us -}
uiUpdate :: Domain -> IO ()
uiUpdate dm = do
    let Domain (usState,s) = dm
    putStrLn usState

{-| Ask user for input. Only a single event is collected. -}
getAction :: IO [Event]
getAction = do
    putStrLn "What do you want to do? Choose between EventExit | EventWalk R | EventWalk L | EventLook"
    act <- readMaybe <$> getLine
    case act of 
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Not a valid action" >> getAction
        Just evt -> pure [evt]


main :: IO ()
main = run  (Domain ("",World 0)) [EventLook]
```

Finally, you might want to look into StateT, so you can abstract away the Domain object being passed around all the time. But that is outside the scope of this question, I guess.

Comment: Thank you LudvigH, for this succinct code. In fact it does what I already doned. And your code now it reflects my problem. But I should somehow,  following your code, when I activate EventWalkDir, after change this state, launch LookEvent ... It is easy to do it !? By the way can I attach two files of code here !? (If someone wants to see it I can share it - I can upload it to github, .. or if I can do from here  !?).

Comment: By the way, I figure it out that your line : run dm [] = uiUpdate dm >> getAction >>= run dm  , uiUpdate dm >> getAction returns an [Event] and this one was passed to "run dm". Is like that no !? Thanks to share it!

Comment: regarding `run dm [] = uiUpdate dm >> getAction >>= run dm` you are right. The `>>=` is a monadic function saying 'give the result of the previous to the next one' it is called "bind"

Comment: to make `look` modify the event-queue I think you should define `data Domain = Domain (UIState,World, [Event]) deriving Show`. Then you will need to change the signature of several functions so that they accept the Domain as input and output all the time. then, that way, they can add to the event queue. but you should really use a state monad for that, in that case. It breaks the structure of your code quite a bit.

Comment: I added the code in Github and passed the URL (see EDIT3), and also an example of execution EDIT2. The problem is that I am wondering how I can execute IO after the state, and for example, when you "walk east" first it changes the domain (so there is a new place), and after that shows the description (let say, without invoke look command). Maybe with full code there is a easy way to do it. Thanks in advance, my target is just learn more of it (and learning by doing).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I am very new at Haskell, and I do not know what is a state monad. And I do not see the idea behind data Domain = Domain (UIState,World, [Event]) ... Maybe I can add the full code.

Comment: I think this is more suitable to continue in chat. Please see this link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234647/landoflisp-in-haskell